# How do I find the start and end point of an Arc? Using center xy, radius and start/end angle values.

Tags: geometry

I'm defining an arc by calling a function like this: arc(x, y, radius*2, radius*2, start, end);

```
x: center x.
y: center y.
radius*2: width.
radius*2: height.
start: start angle in radians or degrees.
end: end angle in radians or degrees.
```

And now I need to "close" the arc by drawing two lines, both from the center of the arc, to the start and end point of the arc.

How do I find the start and end points?

Comment: You know the parametric equations for a circle?

Comment: No I don't think so.

Comment: Well... [you have some reading to do then!](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equation_of_a_circle#Equations). If you get stuck come back with your sticking point.

Comment: If you have different values for width and height, you have an ellipse, not a circle.  Why is radius*2 repeated in the argument list?

Comment: Are you working in GeoGebra?

Comment: @rschwieb thanks, I'll take a look at that.

Comment: @Sigur no I'm using Processing JS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given start angles and end angles you get

```
sX = offsetX + radius * cos(startAngle * PI/180)
sY = offsetY + radius * sin(startAngle * PI/180)
eX = offsetX + radius * cos(endAngle * PI/180)
eY = offsetY + radius * sin(endAngle * PI/180)
```

Multiplying an angle by `PI/180` converts degrees to radians.

Answer (score 2):

After reading http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equation_of_a_circle#Equations as suggested by @rschwieb I came up with the following:

```
s_x = x+radius*Math.cos(startAngle*Math.PI);
s_y = y+radius*Math.sin(startAngle*Math.PI);
e_x = x+radius*Math.cos(endAngle*Math.PI);
e_y = y+radius*Math.sin(endAngle*Math.PI);
```

Comment: If your angles are in radians, you do not need the `Math.PI` factor. If your angles are in degrees, then you will need a factor of `Math.PI/180` instead.